# Learning C# from .NET 3.5 Book

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have basic knowledge of the .net platform and c# language, but i want to improve on that.

I have a printed copy of [Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598849).

It has great reviews and apparently is a great read.

Is it worth reading now at the end of 2012, since there is .NET 4.5 already... plus the book is 1300 pages.

I really don't want to spend a lot of time reading this, just to find out that a big portion of it is irrelevant or I have to "unlearn" stuff in the future.

Comment: Ask here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK, vote to close the topic then.

Comment: It's a good book and worth a read anyway, it teaches many of the fundamentals which are still very valid.

Comment: I would recommend you to start learning from .NET 4.0 instead.. But then its my personal opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Net 4.5 is improvement on 3.5 version, so reading 3.5 version doesn't do any harm but i think, in turn helps in understanding .Net 4.5 easier when you read those books!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use C# with .NET 3.5 as your book, .NET 3.5 is allready installed on your computer if you have .NET 4.5. if you create a new project then you can select the .NET 3.5 
If you allready programmed in other languages then you will get in fast.
You should loock a bit for delegates to understand of sending messages.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to "unlearn" anything. .NET 4.5 adds functionality to .NET 4.0 (which adds) functionality to .NET 3.5.
.NET 3.5 is a great starting point

Answer (score 0):

I do most of my .net work in .net 4.0, however I have had nightmares when having to amend old .net 3.5 code.

Whilst your always best to learn the most up to date frameworks, you should ask what your going to be working on the most, if its legacy 3.5 stuff, then that maybe best.

Also, a lot of the stuff in .net 4 are in addition to .net 3.5, so its certainly not a bad way to improve your skills

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programm .NET 3.5 - its OK.

But if you want to programm C# 5.0 or 4.0 maybe with Visual Studio 2012 or 2010 and .NET 4.0 or 4.5

and you have some money to invest - than new book is your choice =)